# MSCK REPAIR hive external tables

Tags: hive

I have a daily ingestion of data in to HDFS . 
From data into HDFS I generate Hive external tables partitioned by date . 
My qestion is as follows , should I run MSCK REPAIR TABLE tablename after each data ingestion , in this case I have to run the command each day. 
Or running it just one time at the table creation is enough . 
Thanks a lot for your answers

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` while the **structure** or **partition** of the external table is changed. This command updates the metadata of the table.

One example that usually happen, e.g.

You use a field `dt` which represent a date to partition the table.

- Yesterday, you inserted some data which is `dt=2018-06-12`, then you should run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` to update the metadata to tell hive to aware a new partition `dt=2018-06-12`.
- Today, you insert some data which is `dt=2018-06-13`, then you should run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` to update the metadata to tell hive to aware a new partition `dt=2018-06-13`.

Comment: so If I add a new partition for a new day ingestion , I have to run this command , may you confirm please ?

Comment: only if you use the `day` field to partition the table

Comment: When you was creating the table, did you add `PARTITIONED BY` in the statement?

Comment: yes for sure I mentioned PARTITIONED BY date in the hql file creating the table, No I am hesitating either ton pout MSCK REPAIR TABLE at the end of this file if it is going to be run just one time at the creatipn or to put it in a second hql file as it is going to be executed after each add of a daily new partition

Comment: I see. You should run it whenever you have new partition. i.e. a new date in this case.